# How do I create a card deck that returns an answer?

Tags: python, list

```
import random
def shuffled_deck():
   basic_deck = list(range(2, 15))
   random.shuffle(basic_deck)
   return basic_deck
print(shuffled_deck())
def suits():
    Suits_Deck = list('Spades','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds')
    random.shuffle(Suits_Deck)
    return(Suits_Deck)
e = random.randint(0,3)
f = random.randint(0,3)
a = random.randint(0,11)
b = random.randint(0,11)
c = str(input("What is Player 1's name? "))
d = str(input("What is Player 2's name? "))
print(c+ ' drew card ' + shuffled_deck[a] + 'of'+ suits[e]) 
print(d+ ' drew card ' + shuffled_deck[b] + 'of'+ suits[f])'''
```

Okay so basically I need to make a deck of cards. I also have to have the code select a card at random and assign it to a player. For some reason when I try to run the code this error appears.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
      print(c+ ' drew card ' + shuffled_deck[a] + 'of'+ suits[e]) 
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Here `suits` and `shuffled_deck` are function objects. I think you mean `suits(e)`, `shuffled_deck(a)` instead of `suits[e]`, `shuffled_deck[a]`

Comment: You need to get the list by calling `shuffled_deck`, then index it, i.e. `shuffled_deck()[a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is elaboration version from @dspencer and @Praveen answer.

so you want to print like :

- player A drew card 5 of Clubs
- player B drew card 3 of Spades

If this what you want, you might edit your code.

```
import random
def shuffled_deck(n):
   basic_deck = list(range(2, 15))
   random.shuffle(basic_deck)
   return basic_deck[n] 

def suits(n):
    Suits_Deck = ['Spades','Hearts','Clubs','Diamonds']
    random.shuffle(Suits_Deck)
    return Suits_Deck[n]


e = random.randint(0,3)
a = random.randint(0,11)


#first attempt
print(' drew card ' + str(shuffled_deck(a)) + ' of '+ suits(e))
#second attempt
print(' drew card ' + str(shuffled_deck(a)) + ' of '+ suits(e))
```

note in the suits() fucntion, directly make a list using '[ ]' [Python list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)
also your `shuffled_deck[a]`, its not a proper way to call a function, use `shuffled_deck(a)`. 'a' from randomint will be the index of basic_deck List.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `shuffled_deck[a]` use `shuffled_deck()[a]` and 
Instead of `suits[a]` use `suits()[a]`

Both `shuffled_deck` and `suits` are functions that return list, so call function then use index to get the element `fun()[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the list by calling the `shuffled_deck` function, then index the returned list, i.e. `shuffled_deck()[a]` instead of `shuffled_deck[a]`.

The same applies for `suits[a]` - this should be written as `suits()[a]` to first call the function.